# Autolayout take no effect

Tags: swift, autolayout, cartography

I just start to study swift, and when I use Cartography to autolayout views, I have a problem. Here is what happens.

I create a LoginViewController, put all the constrains in a function named "updateConstrains()", and called in the override func viewDidLoad(). If I set the LoginViewController as the window rootViewController in AppDelegate, it works well.

[image: The right layout]

But if I put the LoginViewController as the rootViewController of a UINavigationController as follows:

> window!.rootViewController =
>   UINavigationController(rootViewController: loginViewController)

It become like this:

[image: The autolayout has no effect]

and when print the width and height of the LoginViewController's view. It turns out that:

width = 155, height = 0.

Can anyone tell me what happens?

Comment: can you please paste the code for your Viewcontroller?

Answer (score 0):

A common cause for this is forgetting to set `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false` on the view.

Views which are instanced in code have this property set to `true` by default. This creates a set of auto layout constraints based on the values of `autoresizingMask`. If the autoresizing mask is not correctly defined, which is often the case when auto-layout is used, then the generated constraints will not be what you intended.

See the Apple documentation for [translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) and [autoresizingMask](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/autoresizingMask)